# Plotly.js connecting to Django Rest Framework API - is this possible and if so how?

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework, plotly

I am testing the use of plotly in our company's web application. I know plotly has it's own API but it is possible to connect to the Django Rest framework API since it is python based?

If it is possible - what does the syntax look like? Here is what I have so far:

```
div id="myDiv"></div>
  <script>
  var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
```

Instead of hard-coding the data in 'x' and 'y' - I want to point to the json in the Django rest Framework. Database is MySQL. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but in my case i needed it to connect to data from a model in django. 
To do it i have this in my views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import MyModel

@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    entries = MyModel.objects
    data = entries.values('x', 'y')
    context = {
        'x': [i['x'] for i in data],
        'y': [i['y'] for i in data]
    }
    print(context)
    return Response(context)
```

and in my plot.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

class Plot extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  async reload () {
      let url = '<django server address to view>'
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const info = await res.json();
      console.log(info)
      this.setState({
          x: info.x,
          y: info.y,
      });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
      this.reload();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Plot
        data={[
          {
            x: this.state.x,
            y: this.state.y,
            type: 'scatter',
            mode: 'points-lines',
            marker: {color: 'red'},
          },
        ]}
        layout={ {width: 600, height: 480, title: 'A Fancy Plot'} }
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Plot
```

from there you can use the Plot component in your react app.

However, i wonder if there's a more efficient way to do the query in django to handle huge amounts of data..